# Nagios Notification Period Setting, Will Nagios Hold the Email?

Tags: nagios

I am sorry for getting a little lazy not to try it out, but considering it may be helpful for others too, so I ask this question.

If I set Nagios notification period like: `7 am - 5 pm, Mon-Fri`

Once something happens at `12 am`, will Nagios discard the alert, or it will hold the alert until 7 am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not generate a notification at all (as it is filtered before), but reschedule a new notification to 7am (which will only get send if the status is still not OK at that time).

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/notifications.html